# Materialize CSS datepicker selects wrong year in iPhone X

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4, materialize

I'm using materialize css datepicker:

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

It works perfectly fine in android, chrome and even safari and the iphone simulator. But on the iphone device, when you click on a year it selects a nearby year:

[image: datepciker]

Has this happen to anyone and do you have any idea or suggestion on how could I further debug and solve this issue?

The code is practically an form with a few inputs for the user profile, but this same behavior happens on other pages and I've also tried an empty page:

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="filter_subtitle white-text">Datos Personales</div>

      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="input1" [(ngModel)]="userProfile.firstName" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="input1">Nombre</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="input2" [(ngModel)]="userProfile.lastName" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="input2">Apellidos</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="input3" (change)="birthdayPicked()" type="text" tabindex="-1" class="validate datepicker">
        <label for="input3">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="input4" [(ngModel)]="userProfile.username" type="text" tabindex="-1" class="validate datepicker">
        <label for="input4">Nombre de Usuario</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field  col s12">
        <a (click)="saveProfile()" class="btn bg_color_s">Guardar</a>
      </div>

    </div>
```

The date picker is initialized as follows:

```
import * as M from "../../../assets/js/materialize.js";

export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  materializeDatepicker: any;
  constructor() {
    const parts = this.userProfile.birthday.split("/");
    const birthday = new Date(
      parseInt(parts[2], 10),
      parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
      parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    );
    this.materializeDatepicker = M.Datepicker.init(
      document.querySelector('.datepicker'), {
        format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
        yearRange: [1920,2050],
        defaultDate: birthday,
        setDefaultDate: true,
        container: 'body'
      }
    );

  }

}
```